# Theater seating arrangement probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that n people are seated in a random manner in a row of n theater seats. What is the probability that 2 particular people A and B will be seated next to each other?

The answer that I got from the book:
  There are ${n \choose 2} $ possible pairs of seats that A and B can occupy and of these pairs n-1 compromise 2 adjacent seats. So the answer is $P=\frac{n-1}{{n \choose 2}}$

I don't quite understand how they got this answer though. For the ${n \choose 2}$ part I get that there's n seats and we have to choose 2. But I don't understand the numerator.

Before I had checked the answer, I had answered;
$n!$ ways of seating n people in the n seats
and $(n-1)!$ ways of seating them if A and B must sit next to each other, thus my answer was
$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}\ \ \ \ $

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39569/find-the-probability-that-k-people-sits-adjacent-in-a-row-of-n-seats?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your answer of $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$, you're only counting possibilities where $A$ is always sitting on the same side of $B$. Multiply by the missing factor of $2$, and the answers agree.

Their numerator comes from the fact that there are only $n - 1$ pairs of adjacent seats, in a row of $n$ seats.